# Reference request : Introductory technical analysis

Tags: trading, reference-request, technical-analysis

I want to thoroughly learn about technical analysis, or more exactly, how technical indicators or overlays are used in quantitative trading strategies.

Being a beginner to the area, I can't understand most of the terminology when I read up about indicators (e.g. on stockcharts.com), and just google the terms that I can't understand. But this way of learning seems too haphazard.

Could anyone please suggest an intro-level book that explains not only the technical indicators/overlays, but also the basic concepts (like whipsaw, short/long stop, retracement, divergence, breakout, etc.) that are essential to understand while learning technical analysis?

Answer (score 4):

For me as a beginner, the best book was

> **Technical Analysis of the Financial Markets**: A Comprehensive Guide to
>   Trading Methods and Applications

from *John Murphy*. It was published in 1999 (or so), but has still value. The book describes the base concept of trends, the history of beginning, the oszillators and ratios very well. You should read it. I still use it sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

A good book is [Technical Analysis Explained by Martin J. Pring](https://www.amazon.ca/Technical-Analysis-Explained-Fifth-Successful/dp/0071825177)

Its very well written and very intuitive. Its a very important book on the topic.